# How to enable Inertia on CLoudways

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, cloudways

i have just created my first Laravel Inertia Vue 3 application. However, I encountered problem when hosting it to Cloudways. After i configured everything and try to launch my application it only display this image shown below

[image]

I don't know why it won't run my inertia

can someone tell me what to do?

Comment: I don't think this would have anything to do with the hosting provider. I would double check if inertia is installed properly. Make sure its a regular dependency and not a dev dependency

Comment: I checked, and it is placed in require and not in dev dependency

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I thought of something that worked. I have seen that when doing php artisan serve, changing the env variables was not updated so I found that the env config was cached. In short run this command to clear the cache:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

And if you want to re-cache

```
php artisan optimize
```